# Blender 2.8 Array modifier rotating individual parts

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers

I am currently trying to model a snake with the array modifier. I want the snake to go around the pole (as displayed in the picture) but I want the red (belly) of the snake to be in contact with the pole (as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wInhCU79_IY&list=WL&index=23&t=465s timestamp: 7:59) . At the moment you can see that it is facing towards the outside of the curve.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

I have tried to add an empty and use that as my object offset but this makes it so that the different sections of the snake are not connected properly.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to tilt the vertices? Select your curve, go in *Edit* mode, select the vertices you want, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to tilt, or use the N panel:

[image]

Comment: that did it, thank you!